# Ссылки на ресурсы

Tags: jquery, html

Всем привет!
Есть одна задача...состоит она в следующем: мне нужно на сайте разместить ссылку, но что бы поисковики ее не видели...это я сделал так:

```
    var target = '.link';
    $(target).each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('link') == '') {
                $(this).text('Нет ссылки');
            }
            else {
                $hrefImg = $(this).attr('link');
                window.open($hrefImg, "_blank");
            }
        });
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });
```

HTML код такой

```
<span class="link" link="ссылка тут">Ссылка на ресурс</span>
```

Вроде должно работать, но не знаю точно...Ну это ладно...Следующее что нужно так это сделать так что бы при переходе с этого сайта по ссылке (допустим на site.ru) этот site.ru не распознал что на него попали с этого сайта. Если стоит метрика от яндекса или еще что-то такое (они же увидят откуда пришел к ним пользователь) а мне так не нужно...точнее клиенту...
Вот как-то так! Скажите кто знает это реально вообще, или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы поисковики "не видели" ссылку, используйте `nofollow`:

```
<a href="http://www.targetsite.com/" rel="nofollow">ляляля тополя</a>
```

Для того, чтобы подавить referrer, [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875547/276994) использовать такой трюк:

```
<a href='data:text/html;charset=utf-8, <html><script>window.location = "http://eviltargetsite.com/";</script></html>'>нажми меня!</a>
```

Comment: а замаскировать переход никак?

Comment: @Evgeny Vorobev: обновил ответ

Comment: так получается что у меня правильно... только на jquery

Comment: @Evgeny Vorobev: похоже, что правильно. Можете проверить редирект на эту страницу: http://all-nettools.com/toolbox/environmental-variables-test.php (гляньте, что приходит в HTTP_REFERER).

Comment: работает то как советуют только в случае если нажать правой кнопкой мышки и потом открыть в новой вкладке...а мой никак не работает((

Comment: @Evgeny Vorobev: это объяснимо: ваш вариант использует jquery, а если код будет исполняться в контексте нового окна, там ведь jquery не загружен.

Comment: спасибо! нашел такое решение ---> http://anonym.to/ru.html

Comment: @Evgeny Vorobev: Ну, это решение зависит от существования сервиса anonym.to. Вы можете легко поднять свой собственный аналогичный сервис, чтобы быть независимым от поломок на чужом сайте.